# How to figure out why I'm banned, and why am I getting banned

Tags: support, post-ban

So, just today I was browsing Stack Overflow's questions, fixing grammar, answering posts, then I get a question in my head, when I got to click on the "Ask a Question" tab, it says "We are no longer accepting questions form this account"...  Non of my questions have any downvotes, and I have accepted a best answer for all of them.  Why would I be getting banned from asking questions all the sudden?

This all the sudden happened today.  I don't recall doing anything that made me not able to ask questions anymore.

Comment: Did you delete downvoted questions?

Comment: @juergend No I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one downvoted and three closed questions,  but that is not enough to cause a ban. You most likely have several downvoted or closed questions that are deleted. Deleted questions actually cound *more* towards the ban.

Flag one of your posts, select "Other," and request for a moderator to undelete your deleted questions so you can improve them.

[image: screenshot]

Or, go to your profile, go to the questions tab, scroll all the way down, and find the "deleted recent questions" link:

[image: screenshot]

You may be able to find some of the deleted questions there, and undelete them.

Comment: Or he visits *recent deleted questions* in his profile.

Comment: I don't delete my questions though.

Comment: @juergend Yep, edited

Comment: @user3117575 It's probably because members of the community have voted to delete your questions.

Comment: @user Other users can delete your posts, too.

Comment: Thank you! I can now ask questions again!

Comment: @user3117575 Good! Be careful though, you're probably near the edge of the ban. Be sure to post high quality questions.